# Magento 2.3 how to automatically upload videos to page from youtube channel

Tags: magento2.3, video, youtube, external-script

I want to get all videos from youtube channel and load it on page. How can I do that? Is there some free plugins or mb I need to use some of JavaScript libraries? I found YouTube Gallery Widget, but I'm not sure that it's suits for me.
https://marketplace.magento.com/elfsight-youtubegallery.html
[image]